# Will not deleting a pointer in destructor cause memory leak if reference should stick around?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, heap-memory, destructor

I don't know how to word my question simpler, but say I have this:

```cpp
class Curve;

class Node {
    Curve *curve;
public:
    Node(Curve *curve);
    ~Node();
}

class Curve {
    LinkedList<Node> nodes;
public:
    Curve(); ~Curve();
}
```

Is it okay to not delete the pointer to the curve in the destructor `~Node`? That is, will it cause a memory leak? Or am I supposed to delete it? If I delete it, will it destroy the curve?

Edit: The curve will get deleted eventually.

Edit 2: Implementation.

Say I implement code below:

```cpp
int main() {
    Curve *curve = new Curve();
    Node *node = new Node(curve);
    delete node; delete curve;
    return 0;
}
```

Will I still need to call `delete curve` within the node's destructor?

Comment: If you `new` an object then you must `delete` it. If you don't `delete` it then you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The curve will get deleted eventually.

Comment: If the Curve in Node is not owned by it but just referenced by pointer passed by constructor then you may not delete it in destructor.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you. This is more or less the answer I was looking for.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with deleting something in a destructor that's not `new`ed in the constructor. The only rule that must be followed is that everything gets `new`ed gets `delete`d at some point, somewhere. And that only thing that gets `delete`d is something that was `new`ed, at some point. Now, whether or not something is good design, or not, is a completely different question.

Comment: Are you worried about leaking memory, or memory fragmentation?

Comment: @Eljay Sorry. I think I meant memory leaks. Apologies for the misus of terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, this is about ownership. In your particular example it is ok to not delete Curve* in destructor of the Node class, because you manage the life of Curve instance in main function. In real code managing raw pointers can be quite difficult and lead to nasty errors. Since you tagged the question as C++, you should use standard library's smart pointer and replace Curve* with std::shared_ptr.
In case you change your mind and make Node solely responsible for managing the Curve instance it is a good idea to use std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I've read about smart pointers and am a little new to them since I don't understand when to use which yet. But I think this does give me a better idea.

Comment: In general if you have dynamically allocated object used only in scope of function or you keep it inside of the class, you almost always want to use std::unique_ptr.
If you want to share something between several classes and don't want to make separate copies of your object, you probably should store it using std::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about memory fragmentation, or memory leaks.

This is about:

- ownership:

  - Who owns the resource? `main` (which shares it with the `Node`) or `Node` (to which `main` transfers ownership)? You need to somehow make that clear, either by using smart pointers or via documentation.
- correctness:

  - Only *one* of those things (the thing that has ownership) should do the deletion. You can't delete a thing twice.